# Python filter object not iterating

Tags: python, python-3.x

The python documentary says that `filter()` returns an iterator so why is the last list empty

Also tried putting `list()` and `iter()` around the last `f` and those didn't help.

```
li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def func(x):
    return x**x

print([func(x) for x in li if x%2==0])

f = filter(lambda i: i%2==0,li)
print(f)
print(list(f))
m = map(func,iter(f))
print(list(m))
```

Output:

```
[4, 256, 46656, 16777216, 10000000000]
<filter object at 0x100c57e80>
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[]
```

Comment: Iterators only iterate once.  You consumed `f` when you built a `list` out of it.

Comment: @Samwise Thanks. But then shouldn't map(func,iter(f)) have worked? It didn't tho

Comment: Yes people I know I didn't post code. Was in a lazy mood and this code is so simple it shouldn't matter

Comment: @pmac I was going to explain, but suddenly I'm in a lazy mood.  (Also, how is it easier to snap a screenshot, crop it, and upload it than to just Ctrl-A/Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V the text???)

Comment: @Samwise Haha taste of my own medicine. But it would be much appreciated if you could please explain. I've only been using python for a few weeks.

Comment: @Samwise yea idk there i changed it

Comment: @Samwise nvm, I see saving it to a variable name will allow me to use it again and again